# Can regression coefficients be guaranteed to be normalized?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-preprocessing, constrained-regression

When solving a multivariate linear regression problem of the form $A\vec{x}=\vec{y}$ where $A$ and $\vec{y}$ are known. Is there any from of preprocessing or scaling that can be done $A$ and or $\vec{y}$ that will help me satisfy some constraints on $\vec{x}$? Namely that the $l_2$ norm should be $1$. Or something similar regarding the $l_1$ norm.

Comment: well if the columns of A are orthonormal, and y is a unitary vector then also the norm of x should be 1. but I am not sure this is what you are asking...

Comment: what the effects of orthogonalizing the regressors would be is explained here (for example):
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X13001368

Comment: You can perform *postprocessing* (in many ways) to assure any given norm of $\hat x$ is $1,$ provided $y$ is not identically zero.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm asking specifically about preprocessing....